# Python dataclass, what's a pythonic way to validate initialization arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

What's a pythonic way to validate the init arguments before instantiation w/o overriding dataclasses built-in init?

I thought perhaps leveraging the `__new__` dunder-method would be appropriate?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    is_good: bool = False
    is_bad: bool = False

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance: cls = super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        if instance.is_good:
            assert not instance.is_bad
        return instance
```

Comment: Have you considered simply disallowing the caller to specify values for both fields? For example, set `is_bad: bool = field(init=False)`, then set `self.is_bad = not self.is_good` in `__post_init__`.

Comment: thanks @chepner `field(init=False)` is also a very cool idea.

Comment: You could use [Pydantic dataclasses](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Define [a `__post_init__` method on the class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing); the generated `__init__` will call it if defined:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    is_good: bool = False
    is_bad: bool = False

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.is_good:
            assert not self.is_bad
```

This will even work when [the `replace` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace) is used to make a new instance.

Answer (score 8):

The author of the `dataclasses` module [made a conscious decision](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/60#issuecomment-341921019) to not implement validators that are present in similar third party projects like `attrs`, `pydantic`, or `marshmallow`. And if your actual problem is within the scope of the one you posted, then doing the validation in the `__post_init__` is completely fine.

But if you have more complex validation procedures or play with stuff like inheritance you might want to use one of the more powerful libraries I mentioned instead of `dataclass`. Just to have something to look at, this is what your example could look like using [`pydantic`](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic):

```py
>>> from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
>>> class MyClass(BaseModel):
...     is_good: bool = False
...     is_bad: bool = False
...
...     @validator('is_bad')
...     def check_something(cls, v, values):
...         if values['is_good'] and v:
...             raise ValueError("Can not be both good and bad now, can it?")
...         return v
...     
>>> MyClass(is_good=True, is_bad=False)  # this would be a valid instance
MyClass(is_good=True, is_bad=False)
>>> MyClass(is_good=True, is_bad=True)   # this wouldn't
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 283, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyClass
is_bad
  Can not be both good and bad now, can it? (type=value_error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class MyClass(ValidatedDC):
    is_good: bool = False
    is_bad: bool = False


instance = MyClass()
assert instance.get_errors() is None
assert instance == MyClass(is_good=False, is_bad=False)

data = {'is_good': True, 'is_bad': True}
instance = MyClass(**data)
assert instance.get_errors() is None

data = {'is_good': 'bad_value', 'is_bad': True}
instance = MyClass(**data)
assert instance.get_errors()
print(instance.get_errors())
# {'is_good': [BasicValidationError(value_repr='bad_value', value_type=<class 'str'>, annotation=<class 'bool'>, exception=None)]}

# fix
instance.is_good = True
assert instance.is_valid()
assert instance.get_errors() is None
```

ValidatedDC: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc