# Python dataclass validation: an easy way?

Tags: python, validation, python-dataclasses, marshmallow

I'm trying to understand how python dataclass validation can be implemented straightforwardly. I'm using marshmallow `validate` to try to do this but not understanding how the validation can actually be run within the dataclass, or whether it is just glommed on as a metadata field that you have to rather awkwardly run.

I could do a `__post_init__` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488765/validating-input-when-mutating-a-dataclass) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179799/python-dataclass-whats-a-pythonic-way-to-validate-initialization-arguments)) to directly perform the validation on each field but I feel like there should be an easier, validator-agnostic way to validate all the fields according to their `validate` metadata, either at `__init__` or otherwise.

Here is an example script below:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from marshmallow import validate


def null_validate(value):
    """Validation fn for dataclass"""
    if value is None:
        pass
    else:
        raise ValidationError("{value} should be a string for this dataclass field!")


@dataclass
class Testing:
    plus_minus_one: int = field(
        default=None,
        metadata=dict(
            required=False,
            validate=validate.OneOf([1, -1])
        )
    )
    max_one: int = field(
        default=None,
        metadata=dict(
            required=False,
            validate=validate.Range(max=1)
        )
    )
    null_field: str = field(
        default=None,
        metadata=dict(
            required=False,
            validate=null_validate
        )
    )

print("this passes")
it = Testing(1, 1, None)
print("this should fail")
it = Testing(10, 10, 10)
```

I run this as follows but don't get any `ValidationError`, so I know that the validation doesn't somehow happen magically inside the dataclass:

```
% python testing.py
this passes
this should fail
```

So what I can do is add a `__post_init__` method like this to the dataclass:

```
def __post_init__(self):
    for data_field in self.__dataclass_fields__:
        self.__dataclass_fields__[data_field].metadata["validate"](
            self.__dict__[data_field]
        )
```

With this, the validation more or less works on an argument-wise basis:

```
% python testing.py
this passes
this should fail
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 47, in <module>
    it = Testing(10, 10, 10)
  File "<string>", line 6, in __init__
  File "testing.py", line 41, in __post_init__
    self.__dataclass_fields__[data_field].metadata["validate"](self.__dict__[data_field])
  File "/Users/max.press/miniconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/validate.py", line 569, in __call__
    raise ValidationError(self._format_error(value))
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: Must be one of: 1, -1.
```

But this seems rather clunky, and it seems hard to implement more complex validations than this. It seems like I should be able to validate "up-front" when the argument is passed in, without changing anything.

Is the solution to move to a full `marshmallow-dataclass`? Possibly treating as a `Schema` could handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can do this quite easily by using marshmallow dataclasses and their `Schema()` method.

The below code shows the desired behavior without the `__post_init__`, though I clearly need to read up more on marshmallow:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from marshmallow import validate, Schema
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass



def null_validate(value):
    """Validation fn for dataclass"""
    if value is None:
        pass
    else:
        raise ValidationError("{value} should be a string for this dataclass field!")


@dataclass
class Testing:
    plus_minus_one: int = field(
        default=None,
        metadata=dict(
            required=False,
            validate=validate.OneOf([1, -1])
        )
    )
    max_one: int = field(
        default=None,
        metadata=dict(
            required=False,
            validate=validate.Range(max=1)
        )
    )
    null_field: NoneType = field(
        default=None,
        metadata=dict(
            required=False,
            validate=null_validate
        )
    )

print("this passes")
it = Testing.Schema().load({"plus_minus_one": 1, "max_one": 1, "null_field": None})
print("this should fail")
it = Testing.Schema().load({"plus_minus_one": 10, "max_one": 10, "null_field": 10})
```

When it's run, I get the desired result:

```
this passes
this should fail
[...]
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'null_field': ['Not a valid string.'], 'plus_minus_one': ['Must be one of: 1, -1.'], 'max_one': ['Must be less than or equal to 1.']}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I tryed to use 
from marshmallow import validate, fields
but I can not make it actually validate nor printing a custom error_message

Comment: @parrott I'd suggest asking a separate question with your exact code.